# Why are there non-local tasks on a single-node hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I setup hadoop on a single node, so ResourceManager, Namenode, and Datanode are all running on the same machine.

However, after examining the resourcemanager logs, I noticed that some tasks were not local and they are recorded as being assigned to "off switch" node.

Aren't all tasks supposed to be local when there is only one datanode and everything is on the same machine?